# How to escape a date variable in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, controller

In my rooms controller I want to update a room with some predefined values. The notefield should contain the Date.current but also some additional text. What I want to see in the database would be "This room was updated on 06/05/2016. Thanks!"
I tried several ticks and quotes but nothing seemed to work. What would be the proper way to achieve this in ruby?

```
Room.where(roomnumber: params[:room_numbers]).update_all(createdby: 'd999996', createdfor: 'd999996', kst: '0', note: Date.current)
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the `updated_at` column and style it in the view with a helper?

Comment: The data will be exported into CSV and the guy sorts the table with the text...

Comment: So decorate the date when you generate the CSV. Don't needlessly store piles of duplicated text in the DB. It's just pointless.

Comment: I understand your point. But this would require some additional work as other notefields can contain different data. Also, I have a given and very limited set of rooms.

Comment: A little bit of extra work, and a much higher quality codebase. Completely up to you of course, but I know what I would do.

Comment: Of course you were right after all!

Comment: Haha, this is a blast from the past! Would love to hear how things turned out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
Room.where(roomnumber: params[:room_numbers]).update_all(createdby: 'd999996', createdfor: 'd999996', kst: '0',note: "This room was updated on #{Date.current.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')}. Thanks!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Room.where(roomnumber: params[:room_numbers]).update_all(createdby: 'd999996', createdfor: 'd999996', kst: '0', note: "This room was updated on #{Date.current.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')}. Thanks!")
```

Why do you want to store that text? Maybe it would be better to just store date and later format it like you want for displaying purposes?

Comment: Yes, only date storing is fine. And better serve the note text using i18n set up..